# Finding limit of $\frac{n\sin n!}{n^2+1}$ as $n$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to find$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n\sin n!}{n^2+1}$$using the squeeze (or sandwich) theorem, and I got the result $0$. Is this right? Because the limit as $n$ approaches infinity of $\sin(n)$ is not defined.

Comment: Yes, $\lim\frac{n\sin(n!)}{n^2+1}=0$ even though $\lim\sin (n!) $ does not exist.

Comment: More accurately, the limit of $\sin(n!)$ probably doesn't exist, but we don't know for sure.  See e.g. [this M.O. question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45665/distribution-mod-1-of-factorial-multiples-of-real-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Since $-1\leq \sin n! \leq 1$ we can obtain the limit by the following double inequality and the squeeze theorem.

$$-\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}\leq \dfrac{n\sin n!}{n^2+1}\leq \dfrac{n}{n^2+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

- $-1 \le \sin(\theta) \le 1$ for all $\theta$
- so $-n \le n \sin(n!) \le n$ for all positive $n$

Meanwhile

- $n^2 +1 \gt  n^2 \gt 0$  for all positive $n$
- $0 \lt \dfrac1{n^2 +1} \lt  \dfrac{1}{n^2}$  for all positive $n$

so

- $-\dfrac1n = \dfrac{-n}{n^2} \lt \dfrac{n \sin(n!)}{n^2+1} \lt \dfrac{n}{n^2} = \dfrac1n $
- and $0 = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} -\dfrac1n \le \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n \sin(n!)}{n^2+1}  \le \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1n =0$

Answer (score 0):

$$0<\left|\frac{n\sin(n!)}{n^2+1}\right|<\frac1n$$ squeezes to zero.